# How to handle if internet connectivity of a windows phone 7 app is lost in between when the app is running?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a WP7 app, which needs online connectivity. Before navigating to any page from mainpage.xaml, I am checking whether or not the device is connected to the internet using:

```
isAvailable = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
```

The app only continues if `isAvailable` is true; otherwise, it shows a pop stating "Please check your WI-FI connectivity"

Question: Initially, the app is connected to the internet, but how should I handle situations where internet connectivity is lost while I'm using the app, but after the initial check?

Should I check for `isAvailable = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();` on every page load or before every service call? Is there a better way of implementing this?

Comment: Does listening to the [NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) event help?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation;

public MainPage()

    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
           // Use navigation method here
        }
        else

           MessageBox.Show("Need net connection");
```

Comment: This is what i am using in mainpage.xaml , my question is how to handle it if the internet connection goes off in between in some page in some place how to handle it ?

Comment: You can check the connection while execute any event or method or you can do it often in a specific interval of time.

Answer (score 5):

You should hook into the DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged Event which will allow your application to be notified when the network availability changes, removing the need to check every time you perform a service call :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.networkavailabilitychanged(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 2):

No point on checking NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable on every page. A web request can fail even is the user has internet connectivity, and in fact it will happen pretty often. Just make sure to handle all the error cases, provide automatic or easy-to-use retry mechanisms, and notify the user that the action cannot complete because something is wrong with its connection.